# Who are Reys parents?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I was wondering if you can share your opinions regarding these two theories about *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*. One is that Rey is actually the daughter of Luke Skywalker, and the second idea is that she is just an incarnation of the Midi-Chlorian, just like Anakin.